# Python Prime Number Generator Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, generator, fft

I'm not a programmer, but I'm learning,

Can someone help me understand what FFT is? How do I implement it in a python code, for example say a python code to generate primes from 1 to 10000?

Also somebody suggested NumPy, I downloaded it and installed it, but dont know what it does. Is it related to FFT?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
babsdoc

Comment: FFT as in Fast Fourrier Transform? not sure what that has to do with generating primes...

Comment: Have you tried this new-fangled website called [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=FFT)?

Comment: related: [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/4279)

Comment: thats a nice one @J.F.Sebastian bookmarked!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm going to ignore all that about the fft, (which is related to signal processing and not prime numbers at all).

The most famous basic and famous approach is the [seive of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  Wikipedia has a nice visual example of how it works.

In (untested) Python you'd code it as follows:

```
max_val = 1000
seive = range(max_val)
seive[0] = None  # 1 is not prime!
for x in range(1, max_val):
    if seive[x]:
        print "{prime} is prime.".format(prime = x)
        # now remove multiples of prime x from the seive
        y = 2*x 
        while y <= max_val:
            seive[y] = None
            y = y + x
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggested function from here ["Python: Checking if a number is prime"](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2009/09/python-checking-if-a-number-is-prime/)

I suggest following code for you:

```
def isprime(number):  
if number<=1:  
    return 0  
check=2  
maxneeded=number  
while check<maxneeded+1:  
    maxneeded=number/check  
    if number%check==0:  
        return 0  
    check+=1  
return 1 
prime_list = [i for i in xrange(1,1001) if isprime(i)]
print prime_list

>>> [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, ...
```

Adjust the xrange(**1,1001**) to your desired range and you get all prime numbers